# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage<TModel>.Model.get returned null.Exception.What's the issue?I cant find it

Tags: c#, visual-studio, model-view-controller, mvvm, detailsview

Its crashing on my CardDetailsView,the Details IActionResult in my CardsController

CardDetailsView-

```
public class CardDetailsViewModel
{

    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    public string Destination { get; set; }

    public string Model { get; set; }

    public string SNumber { get; set; }

    public string QNumber { get; set; }

}
```

CardDetailsView-

```
@model CardDetailsViewModel
```

@{ ViewBag.Title = "Details"; }

Card Details
        
            
                Title
                
            
            
                Destination
                
            
            
                Model
                
            
            
                SNumber
                
            
            
                QNumber
                
            
            
                
                    Details

CardsController-

```
public class CardsController : Controller
{
    public readonly DigitalCardsDbContext data;

    public CardsController(DigitalCardsDbContext data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public IActionResult Add() => View();

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Add(CardAddViewModel card)
    {
        if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(card);
        }

        var cardd = new Card
        {
            Title = card.Title,
            ImageUrl = card.ImageUrl,
            Destination = card.Destination,
            Receiver = card.Receiver,
            Model = card.Model,
            UserFullName = card.UserFullName,
            SNumber = card.SNumber,
            QNumber = card.QNumber,
            PublicView = card.PublicView
        };

        this.data.Cards.Add(cardd);
        this.data.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("All","Cards");
    }

    
 
    public IActionResult All()
    {
        var cards = this.data.Cards
            .Where(c => c.PublicView == true).ToList();

        var usern = User.Identity.Name;
       
        if(usern!=this.User.Identity.Name)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        var cardsl = cards  
            .Select(c => new CardAllViewModel
            {
                Id = c.Id,
                Title = c.Title,
                ImageUrl = c.ImageUrl,
                Destination = c.Destination,
                SNumber = c.SNumber,
                QNumber = c.QNumber
            })     
            .ToList();

        return View(cardsl);

    }
   
    public IActionResult Details(string cardId)
    {
        
        var card = this.data.Cards.Where(c => c.Id == cardId)
            .Select(c => new CardDetailsViewModel
            {
                Id = c.Id,                 
                ImageUrl = c.ImageUrl,
                Title = c.Title,
                Destination = c.Destination,
                Model = c.Model,
                SNumber = c.SNumber,
                QNumber = c.QNumber
            })
            .SingleOrDefault();

        return View(card);

    }
```

The code is crashing on my View,on every div class,Title,ImageUrl,Etc.The exception is Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage.Model.get returned null.
Here is snap-[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0DkR.png)

Comment: Can you please post the actual code rather than pictures so we can understand your problem better.

Comment: What i have to post to help you understand it...i am new here

Comment: The actual code blocks that you are showing in your screenshots. And a description of the error you are getting and when are you getting the error.

Comment: I added the Error,and the ViewModel

Comment: Put a check on your `View` for this: `@if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.ImageUrl)){ // render the component}`

Comment: I figured out that every div class crashes with that error in the view(Title,Model,etc),not only the imageUrl...i hope that helps

Comment: It seems that your `Model` is coming as null so check for it before your initialize your components: `@if(Model !=null){ //render your components }` . Basically you need to check in your `Controller` why is your model not populating.

Comment: [Never post images of code or data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers. Please paste more code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Rahul Sharma, i edited  the question..please view the code again

Answer (score 0):

Please verify the value in the image [url] it looks like that could be the reason.

Comment: Thank you,I tried but it seems like it breaks on every div class,i removed the ImageUrl and then crashed on the div class Title,and so on...